# Best Free Windows IDE that supports HTML and CSS with code validation?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS and HTML
So I need a free, clear, understandable, and simple to use
IDE for HTML and CSS and preferably to have a nice UI.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Web Developer 2010 Express from Microsoft looks like what you need:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express

It is a free version of Visual Studio which is specifically aimed at web development, including (but not limited to) HTML and CSS development.

Comment: Do you know of a link that will show me how to set up 
Visual Web Develop 2010?

Comment: Well, there's a big blue button which sais "Install now" :) I'm not sure what you mean by setting it up. Install it, create a solution, add files and edit them.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Dreamweaver is a nice IDE.

Thanks

Edit

Dreamwaver is not free IDE. [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) is a good free IDE.

Comment: Should install the eclipse plug-in version, or just the standalone version? (I will use it only for HTML, CSS)

Comment: I suppose if you will do development also, you should install eclipse and then aptana plugin. But if your work only HTML/CSS then standalone version would be perfect for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

A simple, web based, solution to what you want is [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/). Lets you edit html and css and see the results live.